# IIS Hosting multiple websites

Tags: asp.net-mvc, windows, iis-7, hosting

I have an IIS server hosting 40-50 ASP.Net MVC websites.
Each website has its own ApplicationPool.

When I need to restart the server for updates or config changes it takes about 3 hours for IIS to startup again.  If I change each appPool to not Start Immediately IIS starts as normal and I have to go through each appPool to start them up manually.  Which is a pain but it is faster.

Any Ideas why these AppPools should be taking so long to startup?

Regards
Carl

Comment: Please open a support case via http://support.microsoft.com and work with Microsoft support on that.

Comment: It might be simple concurrency issue.

As you have so many websites in IIS and all of those are launched at the same moment, they end up rushing forward for HDD, CPU, Memory resources, which put too much of load on hardware and OS internals.
It is just a clue, but it is very common scenario in different areas.